# Change font to times in Dissertate template? (all bold/italic formatting disappears)

Tags: fonts, templates, dissertate

I am using the `Dissertate` class for a CS dissertation.

I want to change all fonts (text & math) to Times. My efforts to do this by adding:

`\usepackage{times}`

under the top `\documentclass` statement works, but *removes all bold/italic/etc. formatting*.

I assume fonts are encoded into the main `.cls` doc -- can anyone point out the fix?

The template is here:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-and-dissertation-latex-templates-for-harvard-princeton-and-new-york-university-nyu/wkzvtymyxqvv

**Here is the `Dissertate.cls`:**

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
%  @LaTeX-class-file{
%     filename        = "Dissertate.cls",
%     version         = "1.0",
%     date            = "24 January 2014",
%     codetable       = "ISO/ASCII",
%     keywords        = "LaTeX, Dissertate",
%     supported       = "send email to suchow@post.harvard.edu",
%     docstring       = "Class for a dissertation."
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Dissertate}[2014/01/24 v1.0 Dissertate Class]
\LoadClass[12pt, oneside, letterpaper]{book}

% some definitions
\def\degreeyear#1{\gdef\@degreeyear{#1}}
\def\degreemonth#1{\gdef\@degreemonth{#1}}
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
\def\advisor#1{\gdef\@advisor{#1}}
\def\department#1{\gdef\@department{#1}}
\def\field#1{\gdef\@field{#1}}
\def\university#1{\gdef\@university{#1}}
\def\universitycity#1{\gdef\@universitycity{#1}}
\def\universitystate#1{\gdef\@universitystate{#1}}
\def\programname#1{\gdef\@programname{#1}}
\def\pdOneName#1{\gdef\@pdOneName{#1}}
\def\pdOneSchool#1{\gdef\@pdOneSchool{#1}}
\def\pdOneYear#1{\gdef\@pdOneYear{#1}}
\def\pdTwoName#1{\gdef\@pdTwoName{#1}}
\def\pdTwoSchool#1{\gdef\@pdTwoSchool{#1}}
\def\pdTwoYear#1{\gdef\@pdTwoYear{#1}}

\RequirePackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\RequirePackage[tiny, md, sc]{titlesec} 
\RequirePackage[large, bf]{titlesec} 
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{plain}
\RequirePackage{titling}
\RequirePackage[palatino]{quotchap}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareStringOption{School}[]
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\RequirePackage{packages/\Dissertate@School/style}

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\RequirePackage[comma, square, authoryear]{natbib}
%\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{[#1]}
\RequirePackage[width=5.75in, letterpaper]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

%\RequirePackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\setthesection}{\arabic{chapter}.A\arabic{section}}

\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage[tight,nice]{units}
\RequirePackage{verbatim}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\RequirePackage{url}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize \scshape}
% \usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of figures}
\RaggedRight

\parindent 12pt
\RequirePackage{mathspec}

\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Proportional},SizeFeatures={{Size=-8, OpticalSize=8},{Size= 8-, OpticalSize=12}},]{EB Garamond}
\setmathrm{EB Garamond}

\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\newfontfamily{\smallcaps}[RawFeature={+c2sc,+scmp}]{EB Garamond}
\setromanfont[Numbers=OldStyle, Ligatures={Common, TeX}, Scale=1.0]{EB Garamond}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, BoldFont={Lato Bold}]{Lato Regular}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Mono} % Font substitution for Source Code Pro

\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf,footnotesize,singlespacing},
                                textfont={sf,footnotesize,singlespacing},
                                justification={justified,RaggedRight},
                                singlelinecheck=false,
                                margin=0pt,
                                figurewithin=chapter,
                                tablewithin=chapter]{caption}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

%\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing

% an environment for paragraph-style section
\providecommand\newthought[1]{%
   \addvspace{1.0\baselineskip plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}%
   \noindent\textsc{#1}%
}

% Align reference numbers so that they do not cause an indent
\newlength\mybibindent
\setlength\mybibindent{0pt}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
    {\chapter*{\bibname}%
     \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
     \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}
          {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{999}}
           \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\dimexpr\labelsep+\mybibindent\relax\itemindent-\mybibindent
           \@openbib@code
           \usecounter{enumiv}
           \let\p@enumiv\@empty
           \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}
     \sloppy
     \clubpenalty4000
     \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
     \widowpenalty4000%
     \sfcode`\.\@m}
    {\def\@noitemerr
      {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}
     \endlist}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This class file loads an OpenType font and sets the encoding to Unicode. A legacy package like `times` won’t work. You want to `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` instead.

Comment: You then also want to `\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin){TeX Gyre Termes}`, since the template sets that as well. It would be even better to load `unicode-math` and TeX Gyre Termes Math.

Comment: Thank you!  Adding \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} up where \setmathsfont i defined does nothing, but adding it at the end of the cls file works. I assume it's overwriting a different option set elsewhere.